# Disabled no funciona, en materialize 1.0.0

Tags: materialize

Estoy tratando de deshabilitar un botón con la clase `disabled`, pero no lo deshabilita la versión de material es la **v1.0.0**.

```html
<a class="col s6 left btn modal-trigger btn_my_ranking disabled" href="#modal_my_ranking">
```

Comment: Debes de subir el problema que estas teniendo

Comment: saludos, es mejor si agregas tu codigo para darte una posible respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El atributo **disabled** solo funciona en elementos de tipo:

- button
- fieldset
- input
- optgroup
- option
- select
- textarea

Pero no en elementos `<a>`, si haz conseguido un efecto de des-habilitado mediante *css/js* comprueba que estés cargando los ficheros correspondientes, las versiones de compatibilidad y que no tengas errores en consola.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar js para solucionar tu problema:
Creas dos funciones (si quieres habilitar nuevamente) y simular el funcionamiento de un bloqueo.

```html
<a id="disableable" href="#modal_my_ranking" onclick="disable(this.target)">

<script>
  function disable(element){
    element.dataset.dishref = element.href;
    element.href = '#';
    element.style="opacity:0.6; cursor: not-allowed;";
  }
  function enable(element){
    element.href = element.dataset.dishref;
    element.style="";
  }
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que no hayas incluido el css correcto ya que a mí me funciona muy bien en Chrome.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" integrity="sha256-OweaP/Ic6rsV+lysfyS4h+LM6sRwuO3euTYfr6M124g=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js" integrity="sha256-U/cHDMTIHCeMcvehBv1xQ052bPSbJtbuiw4QA9cTKz0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a class="col s6 left btn modal-trigger btn_my_ranking disabled" href="#modal_my_ranking">disabled</a>
<a class="col s6 left btn modal-trigger btn_my_ranking" href="#">enabled</a>
```